# Maximum size of upper shadow minus original family

Tags: co.combinatorics

For $\mathcal{F} \subseteq 2^{[n]}$, define its *upper-shadow* $\partial^+\mathcal{F}$ as follows:

$\partial^+\mathcal{F}=\{A\cup \{x\}|A \in \mathcal{F}\wedge x \in [n] \setminus A\}$.

My question is, what is $\max_{\mathcal{F}\subseteq 2^{[n]}}|\partial^+\mathcal{F}\setminus \mathcal{F}|$? can it be as high as $(1-O(\frac{1}{n}))2^n$, for example?

Note: I asked a similar question in the more restrictive case where $\mathcal{F}\subseteq 2^{[n]}$ is a union-closed family, in which case $|\partial^+\mathcal{F}\setminus \mathcal{F}|\leq 2^{n-1}$.

Comment: Your formal definition of $\delta^+$ seems much stronger than simply "covering some set", and defines the sets exactly one element away from some $A$. Could you please make the two notions agree?

Comment: I think the common definition of "$y$ covers $x$ for a partial order $\leq$, is $x<y$ and there is no element $z$ such that $x<z<y$. Anyway, I've edited the question to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: $(1 - O(\frac{\ln n}{n}))2^n$ can be achieved with a straightforward probabilistic method. Not sure how to improve on this yet.

Comment: @MikhailTikhomirov: Can it help to choose sets $A$ with the probabilities depending on the size of $A$?

Comment: @Seva I tried optimizing with respect to size-dependant probabilities but got nowhere.